# Getting error after login using SSO Auth0\SDK\Exception\ApiException client_secret is mandatory

Tags: laravel, single-sign-on, auth0

Getting following error,

Auth0\SDK\Exception\ApiException
client_secret is mandatory
http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth0/callback?code=vR2IkBVORN2Y75OD&state=8013049a16eaa527e6a08eef9362cd08

[image]

Comment: You did not sent send client_secret in request after callback, simple

Comment: Where I need to send? @Maksim

Comment: from your callback route. maybe you don't put it into env.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I already added in .env file but not working @Maksim.

Comment: the error is because you don't send client_secret. why and how? try to debug you route, check request, put here details of this debug. For now your question is unanswerable.